# JavaFX Slider: How to only change value when dragging is done while also maintaining keyboard / touch support

Tags: javafx, graph, keyboard, slider

[image: JavaFX Slider Graph Application]

How can I make the application so that the graph will only update when the slider has been let go, while still maintaining keyboard / touch screen support?

Replacing valueProperty().addListener() with setOnMouseReleased() will not allow the value to be changed with keyboard or touch screen anymore.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;

public class SavingsCalculatorApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        
        LineChart chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 10);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setPadding(new Insets(20, 40, 0, 40));
        
        XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();
        chart.getData().add(data);
        
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(event -> {
            data.getData().clear();
            for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
                data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(counter, counter * slider.getValue()));
            }
        });
        
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().add(slider);
        layout.getChildren().add(chart);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(SavingsCalculatorApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `valueChanging` property. You can respond when the value changes and `valueChanging` is false, which will happen if the slider changes by the keyboard (or programmatically), or when the `valueChanging` changes from `true` to `false` (which will happen when a change due to the mouse is completed):

```
    slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if ( !slider.isValueChanging()) {
            updateChart(newValue.doubleValue(), data);
        }
    });
    
    slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, wasChanging, isNowChanging) -> {
        if (! isNowChanging) {
            updateChart(slider.getValue(), data);
        }
    });
```

with

```
private void updateChart(double value, XYChart.Series data) {
    data.getData().clear();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(counter, counter * value));
    }
}
```

Never use low-level input events (mouse events, key events, etc) for semantic changes in a control. Always register listeners on the control's properties instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up. It works perfectly. I really appreciate it.